# How to tell if a TLS server requested a client certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, openssl, client-certificates

I'm making TLS client connections in Node.js. Some servers I communicate with request a client certificate. I'd like to be able to detect when this has been requested, so I can log it. At the protocol level I believe this is sent along with the TLS server hello, so the data is there, but I'm not sure how I can get at it.

I'm never actually providing a client certificate for now, I'm just aiming to report which servers requested one.

I think there's probably two cases here:

- A cert has been requested, not provided, and the server has accepted the connection anyway (and then probably given my some kind of 'not authenticated' response).
- A cert has been requested, not provided, and the server has rejected the TLS connection entirely.

At the moment I can't detect either case, solutions for either or both very welcome.

Comment: You can detect the second case trivially, as the server will close the connection without even reading the request. To detect the first case you need to install whatever the OpenSSL equivalent of a Java KeyManager is, and see if is called.

Comment: The server could close the connection for other reasons though - I'd much prefer something that confirms it's due to the client certificate, e.g. an SSL alert code that specifically indicates this case.

Comment: On the Java KeyManager point: I can't find anything like that in the Node docs, but that does sound like a good approach, if it's possible.

Comment: @user207421+ nodejs uses almost the default mode of OpenSSL's API, which requires the key+cert(s) to be configured _before_ the handshake (specifically when creating the SecureContext) and then either uses them if requested (regardless of any CAnames requested by the server) but doesn't tell you which/what actually happened. Tim: In TLS1.3 there is a specific alert, certificate_required=116, but below that it's not very consistent. For versions using OpenSSL 1.0.2 up, which I think should be pretty much all by now, you could turn on `enableTrace` and grovel over the output.